# Ptys (Pseudo terminals) internal buffer size

Tags: linux, terminal

I am trying to emulate both master and slave Ptys but don't know that what is the buffer limit and does it varies on different versions of Linux?
Is there any way(system call) to get the max size of buffer, master and slave use to read and write?

Comment: What did try and find out?

Comment: @yass I tried to some ioctl call like FIONREAD, TIOCINQ and TIOCOUTQ but it only return how many bytes are there in input/output buffer, not the buffer limit or max size. :(

Comment: @BabaRocks The limit is the slave input queue. There's no master output queue -> actually TIOCOUTQ returns /always/ "0" for ptys in Linux (?.x ... 3.x ... 5.x). https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/tty/pty.c?id=d2ec3f77de8e67b7a3dab3ec827467e0fd797c86 Line 142 `Report how much we have in the transmit queue. As everything is instantly at the other end this is easy to implement.`  ---> `return 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyways, I found the answer myself. I read and verified (with my program) the following line from the book "Kerrisk, Michael. The Linux Programming Interface". **On Linux, the pseudoterminal capacity is about 4 kB in each direction** (Master-->slave and slave --> master).

Comment: I send a big chunk in one go and got 4047 (not 4kB=4096) on the other side so I doubt this value is correct in 2022.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

I've empirically determined that this number changes across versions of Debian:

**`ptsbufsize.py`:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from pty import openpty
from fcntl import fcntl, F_GETFL, F_SETFL
from itertools import count

def set_nonblock(fd):
    flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)
    flags |= os.O_NONBLOCK
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags)

master, slave = openpty()

set_nonblock(slave)

for i in count():
    try:
        os.write(slave, b'a')
    except BlockingIOError:
        i -= 1
        break

print("pts write blocked after {} bytes ({} KiB)".format(i, i//1024))
```

#### Debian 8

```
$ uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u6 (2015-11-09)

$ ./ptsbufsize.py
pts write blocked after 134144 bytes (131 kB)
```

#### Debian 9

```
$ uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19)

$ ./ptsbufsize.py
pts write blocked after 19456 bytes (19 KiB)
```